# Typescript - Destucturing function parameter to array

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Why this code produce errors?

```
let promises = [p1(), p2(), p3()];
$q.all(promises)
  .then(([p1Result, p2Result, p3Result]) => {
    // ...
  });
```

But when I turn it to this, it works:

```
let promises = [p1(), p2(), p3()];
$q.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    let [p1Result, p2Result, p3Result] = results;
    // ...
  });
```

Another problem I have is that I can't define a type for `p1Result`, `p2Result`, `p3Result`. Not to mention that Typescript compiler does not infer types of them.

Comment: What do you get in the output for both code snippets?

Comment: Ideally both should just work fine. And you can define the type as `[p1Result, p2Result, p3Result]:[p1Type, p2Type, p3Type]` or even `results:[p1Type, p2Type, p3Type]`. What is the error you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both work the same

## TypeScript

```
declare var $q: any;
declare var p1: any;
declare var p2: any;
declare var p3: any;
let promises = [p1(), p2(), p3()];


$q.all(promises)
  .then(([p1Result, p2Result, p3Result]) => {
    // ...
  });

$q.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    let [p1Result, p2Result, p3Result] = results;
    // ...
  });
```

## Generated JavaScript:

```
var promises = [p1(), p2(), p3()];
$q.all(promises)
    .then(function (_a) {
    var p1Result = _a[0], p2Result = _a[1], p3Result = _a[2];
    // ...
});
$q.all(promises)
    .then(function (results) {
    var p1Result = results[0], p2Result = results[1], p3Result = results[2];
    // ...
});
```

You can [see that TypeScript is happy with both code samples](http://goo.gl/GERkX3)

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a bug in VS 2015. Your code gets intellisense error in VS but compiles successfully. I was relying on intellisense.

Comment: I am using it and it gives me the best experience working with typescript, but because of other parts of code in that project we were using VS. Actually I was thinking about this today ;)

Comment: Actually, It was Resharper's bug!